# Web API Key missing in firebase

Tags: firebase, livechat

I'm trying to get an API key for a live chat plugin, but I can't get the key from Firebase.

**No Web API Key for this project:**

[image]

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the authentication tab and enable a sign-in method (for example email/password). This will generate the web api key.

EDIT: as fen1ksss said: It seems this has been changed just recently. You don't actually need to toggle any of the providers to make it work.

there's been another small change: the authentication tab is now inside the "Engage" tab because google likes hide and seek. once there, follow as above.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems this has been changed just recently. You don't actually need to toggle any of the providers to make it work.

Comment: Yes, can confirm. Nowadays, simply pressing 'Get started' under the Authorization tab in the Firebase console, will generate the Web API key. But without doing this, the key won't be generated.

Comment: I encountered this missing "Web API Key missing in firebase" token today, to resolve the issue I had to "add user", a dummy user in the firebase under Authentication > Users after enabling an email/password authentication sign-in method

Comment: In 2024 I still *did* have to add email/password to authentication methods to get it to give me a Web API Key.  I guess I skipped the "Get Started" Button.

Comment: I can confirm in Feb 2024 that this still works, but not instantly, it will take between 5-10 mins to be visible in config panel.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-id/settings/general/ where project-id is your project's id, should show you your api key written directly under your gcp resource location as "Web Api Key"
Also if you have gotten the config object from your firebase project before, your web api key is listed under the key "apiKey"

Comment: Thank you mr.kevin but as you can see in the screenshot above in my question form it's shows no web api key for this project!!

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I didn't notice the link with the image